# HTTPS broken for this StackExchange meta site

Tags: bug, support, status-planned

For every Stackexchange and Stackexchange meta site I have tested, HTTPS works as expected.

The exception is this site.  When attempting to access this site via HTTPS (https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/) Firefox delivers this error:

> Your connection is not secure
>
> The owner of meta.ux.stackexchange.com has **configured their website improperly**. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

Can someone fix it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue, which is planned to be fixed in late October of some unspecified year, per [Adam's explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266711):

> you can't have a wildcard in the middle of a cert, so meta.*.stackexchange.com could never be a thing and we're not about to start registering/maintaining 100+ certs.
>
> So. We're working on moving meta sites to a different URL scheme (*.meta.stackexchange.com) to get around this. It's a move that was planned earlier, but was held back by universal login... which is now functionally complete. Unfortunately, there's a bunch of other stuff going on at the same time, so this switch is unlikely to happen until late October.
>
> In the meantime, I suggest not using HTTPS on meta sites since it's technically unsupported anyway.

Comment: Thanks sandwich (or sushi, as the case may be).  Is that the same bug as I'm reporting?  What's interesting is that all the other meta sites I tested work fine.

Comment: Thanks sandwich.  I hope they get it working.  I'm used to only linking to HTTPS URLs.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Which metas did you test? All child metas of the form `meta.*.stackexchange.com` should be broken the same way. meta.stackexchange.com will be fine, as will any metas on their own custom domains (MSO, Super User meta, etc.). This is a known issue, with a fix planned, but currently not specific timeline for a fix.

Comment: @Adam Missed it by *that* much.  So sorry, the system on which I performed the ad hoc testing was repurposed just over an hour ago.  The great news is that you know about this issue and have a plan to fix it.  We look forward to your success with that plan.  I've read your post regarding the issue, and it makes good sense... as does your solution. :-)